# Stuck on last puzzle of level 7

Tags: vim-adventures

The puzzle, with two moves to solve, is:

[image]

My keyboard is:

[image]

The nature of the puzzle dictates I get to the second `(` in a single move so that I can expend my last one moving up. (For those familiar with `vim` but not the game, my starting square is the yellow highlighted `-`.)

This level is mostly about the <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys. The ability to recall <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd> commands with  <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> persists in between attempts and puzzles.

Clearly I'm supposed to enter in some command, retry the puzzle, and back-peddle to the second `(` with <kbd>,</kbd> but I can't find a command that takes me there. I thought <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> would do the trick but when I rerun it with <kbd>,</kbd> it places me on the first `*` for some reason.

I would also expect <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>; <kbd>;</kbd> to work but I meet with the same fate.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at :O

Comment: @DrFish [This was my reaction to it](http://www.diapordia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/308922_340480932706283_543567296_n.jpg)

Comment: It's a game that teaches how to use vim, a sort of power-user text editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out <kbd>%</kbd> is smart enough to know what to do in this situation.

Comment: This works because `%` moves to the matching opening/closing brace, which in one presses takes you to the brace just before the exit.

Comment: My amateur mistake was forgetting that you didn't have to be __sitting__ on the closing paren to go to the opening one. Great hint without spelling it out too much, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`f(`, reset, `,`, `,` ?

Seems to work in vim itself, though my keybinds stop me from trying `;` :)

e: I forgot the 2-step limit, so this won't fly.

Comment: That's the closest I've gotten yet, but as noted above: The nature of the puzzle dictates I get to the second `(` in a single move so that I can expend my last one moving up. Two `,`s means no `k` to escape the puzzle.

Comment: Can you do `2,` ?

Comment: As shown on the keyboard, I don't have access to numbers yet. :/

Comment: I'm beginning to think this must be a bug; `t3` really ought to work.

Comment: It doesn't work in vim though, so why would it work in the game?

Comment: So when I hit `,` in vim, it wants another key input; does it act the same in the game? If so, try `f3` and then `,h`

Comment: Thanks for your help! The ingame behaviour is limited to just `,` it appears.

Comment: Final bit of help I can offer; Google found a question on the V-A Facebook page, and the page author gave a hint: can be solved by paying close attention to the hint of the girl with the yellow shirt in the house left of the text ("The nice thing about it...").

Comment: That would have indeed helped, looking back, Someone else pointed out the answer to me: `%`.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>
 would reach the second `(`.

Comment: This suggestion requires 3 keystrokes, but that particular puzzle allows only 2 keystrokes -- one of which must be `k` to exit the puzzle.  So, really there is only 1 keystroke to get to the second `(`.